# Confusion in order by clause in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

I want to use `order by clause` to return 'id' column value of my table in sorted order like '1,2,3,4..' but the the following query returning value of id in the order '1, 10, 100, 101, 102...'

```
select id from loginuser order by id;
```

May I know can I get my desirable output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your id column is of type varchar, try casting to int in the order by clause to get the desired result.

Comment: `SELECT id FROM loginuser ORDER BY CAST(id AS INTEGER) ASC;`

Answer (score 2):

if possible you should change the column type in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Greco's answer, it is good practise to expose the sort order to the caller. Anyhow, using an expression in the `ORDER BY` clause violates SQL Standards. Therefore, consider this alternative:

```
SELECT id, CAST(id AS INTEGER) AS sort_col  
  FROM loginuser 
 ORDER 
    BY sort_col;
```

Comment: @marc_s: "Typically, you cannot refer to a column alias when introduced in the same query.... did you really test this? I doubt it'll even run...." -- you have it *completely* the wrong way around. The SQL-92 spec states you can *only* refer to an "alias" (or `as clause`) in the `ORDER BY` clause. You have doubts? So why don't *you* test it? ;)